# set table of content page font size ,chapter, section and subsection font size each to value

Tags: table-of-contents, overleaf

I have a template with this code for the table of content

```
    \newcommand{\tocheader}{{%
      \underline{\textbf{\larger{Title}}} \hfill \underline{\textbf{\larger{Page}}}\large
      \par\bigskip% After heading
      }}
    \newcommand{\AtBeginShipoutClear}{\gdef\AtBegShi@Hook{}}
    
    \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
        \cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addchaptertocentry{\normalfont\contentsname}
        \section*{\Large\centering\contentsname \\[2cm]
            \underline{\textbf{\larger{Title}}} \hfill \underline{\textbf{\larger{Page}}}\large
            \@mkboth{%
               \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
      \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
            \tocheader 
            }
      }
      \onehalfspacing\@starttoc{toc}%
    }
```

I made the title and page appear in every page with this `\tocheader`-

The problem is, that the page numbering font size is not fixed: W want it all to be 12pt or `\normalsize`.

[image]

I have tried `\usepackage{tocloft}`.

Font changes to ToC content of sectional units

```
    \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
```

but it is also not working and removes some chapters.

I have also tried the font size for chapters, sections and subsections and it also makes the page number the same as for the chapter or section.

```
    \renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}% \part font in ToC
    \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\large\itshape}    % \chapter font in ToC
    \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont\slshape}           % \section font in ToC
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont\itshape}        % \subsection font in ToC
```

I want the chapter's font 16pt, section's 14pt and subsection's 12pt, and spacing as 1.5 cm and the page number font size as 12pt.

Comment: Please try to provide a MWE (minimal working example) following the demands you find here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952, so that we can better understand the problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to cobble together an MWE based on the code in your question. It seems to do the job except for the ToC header but that is your code.

```
% tocprob.tex  SE 594371
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\tocheader}{{%
  \underline{\textbf{\larger{Title}}} \hfill \underline{\textbf{\larger{Page}}}\large
  \par\bigskip% After heading
  }}
\newcommand{\AtBeginShipoutClear}{\gdef\AtBegShi@Hook{}}

\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addchaptertocentry{\normalfont\contentsname}
    \section*{\Large\centering\contentsname \\[2cm]
        \underline{\textbf{\larger{Title}}} \hfill \underline{\textbf{\larger{Page}}}\large
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
        \tocheader 
        }
  }
%  \onehalfspacing\@starttoc{toc}% % where is \onehalfspacing defined????
%}  % this is one } too many

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}% \part font in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\Large\itshape} % \chapter font in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont\large\slshape}  % \section font in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont\itshape}     % \subsection font in ToC

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As far as I can tell it produces the kind of ToC you are after (page numbers all same size). I know that the font for the chapter page is bold, but if you don't want that then use `\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}` as you gave in one of your code lines.